# Vim Copy to System Clipboard without overwriting the default register(")

Tags: vim

When I use `"+y` to copy to the system clipboard, the selected content is copied to the `+` register as well as the default(") register. How can I ensure that the content is copied only to the `+` register without modifying the `"` register?

EDIT:
I now understand that this is the intended behavior and any yanking will modify the default register. I still want to know whether there's a workaround for this.

I have come with a naive solution

for visual mode

`vnoremap <Leader>y :<C-u>let @+=@*<CR>`

and for single line in

`nnoremap <Leader>yy :<C-u>let @+=getline('.') . "\n"<CR>`

But we will be missing many yank features. I hope someone provides a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a custom operator; `:help :map-operator` has the details and an example. With that function, you can then also easily implement the visual mode (already shown in the example) and `yy` mappings (use `v:count . 'yy'`) easily.

To avoid that the yank clobbers the default register, wrap the logic in the following that saves and restores that register:

```
let l:save_clipboard = &clipboard
set clipboard= " Avoid clobbering the selection and clipboard registers.
let l:save_reg = getreg('"')
let l:save_regmode = getregtype('"')
" some yank
call setreg('"', l:save_reg, l:save_regmode)
let &clipboard = l:save_clipboard
```